# Unhandled IOException when instantiating ResponseException for test

Tags: java, spring, elasticsearch

Trying to create a unit test for an elastic search exception handler that uses ResponseException
but having trouble setting up the object. Mocking doesn't work as ResponseException is a final class.

```
private ResponseException responseException = new ResponseException(response);
```

produces the following compilation error:
Unhandled exception: java.io.IOException

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typical Java trick for this case:

```java
private ResponseException responseException = create(response);

private ResponseException create(Response response) {
  try {
    return new ResponseException(response);
  } catch(Exception ex) {
    throw new RuntimeException(ex);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding mockito-inline dependency will enable mockito to mock final classes.

```
'org.mockito:mockito-inline:2.15.0'
```